# Why display Password Strength password don't work on jQuery Form Validator?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to buys register and log in using Jquery form validation library.

and I got a different thing when I copy all form validation code to keep it in my website source code because I don't used **CDN**

And I keep the this library like this

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the Jquery library which i keep on my website

```
<script src="<?PHP echo base_url('asset/main/desk/bootstrap/js/validation.js');?>"></script>
```

***Problem*** If I used CDN (link to resource of jquery form-validator) my password validation will show as bellow option like : bad,weak,good,strong depend of password amount.

**And** If I don't use CDN and I will use validation.js which existing in my website source the password validation show only **The password isn't strong enough**.  Its doesn't show this option **"bad,weak,good,strong"**,

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.validate({
                    rules: {},
                    modules: 'security',
                    onModulesLoaded: function () {
                        var optionalConfig = {
                            fontSize: '12pt',
                            padding: '4px',
                            bad: 'Very bad',
                            weak: 'Weak',
                            good: 'Good',
                            strong: 'Strong'
                        };
                        $('input[name="pass"]').displayPasswordStrength(optionalConfig);
                    }
                });
   });
    </script>
```

Here is the form

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" >Password<span id="pw-error">Password</span></label>
   <div class="control">
       <input data-validation="strength" data-validation-strength="3" type="password" name="pass" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have to use the form validation library by using CDN only and if i want to copy this library to my website source I will can't get the **OptionalConfig** right?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since you posted this but I was having the same problem today. I thought i'd post an answer in case you're still stuck or anyone else in the future becomes stuck.

For some reason the **.displayPasswordStrength()** property is included in the **location module**. Therefore in order for it to work you must also include that module. The code below works:

```
$.validate({
 form : '#my_form',
 modules : 'date, security, location',
 onModulesLoaded: function($form) {
   var optionalConfig = {
     fontSize: '12px',
     padding: '4px',
     bad : 'Very bad',
     weak : 'Weak',
     good : 'Good',
     strong : 'Strong'
   };
   $('input[name="pass"]').displayPasswordStrength(optionalConfig);
 },
 onSuccess : function($form) {
   alert("it works!");
 }
});
```